# Yun shield with javascript / cylonjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, cylon.js

I was wondering if the yun shield would be compatible with nodejs.

I know that the Arduino yun works with cylonjs and nodejs but not the yun shield with the Arduino mega or uno.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to buy a yun shield and see if it works. Then I will post if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

it's not sure since i don't have the yun shield to try (i do have an arduino yun though),

but in theory, **yes you can** !

reading the [wiki for the shield](http://wiki.dragino.com/index.php?title=Yun_Shield#Example_4:_Use_MQTT), since you can install packages, the you can simply run `$ opkg install node`

Comment: So how would it work, because the yun shield doesn't have a sd card?

Comment: You use the USB storage instead, or the  inboard flash memory (16Mb). Even on my arduino yun i didn't need  to add an external storage so far (neither sd  card nor  USB)